# Cleanest way to save Int Array CoreData Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I do have a simple `Integer Array` that I want to save/load to `CoreData`.

Do you have example of the best way to do both of the methods ?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385769/3400991

Comment: I think it's a bit different

Comment: A simple integer? What does it represent? Because if it has a "real" meaning, you could create an entity for it, and use a one to many relationship, else, your could also save the int, as data (using for example JSON representation, NSCoding), as String (componentsJoinedByString), etc.

Comment: it's an Integer Array that represent "choices history" from QuestionsForm
something like that [2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4...]

Comment: *Fastest, but not cleanest way*: Declaring CoreData's field as `Transformable` with `[Int]` as `Custom Class` (assuming you set code generation to Swift for the model) will work. CoreData will archive/dearchive data behind offscreen.

Comment: I did an extension of Array<Int> to String and vice versa, this way I store my array as String in CoreData

Answer (score 3):

Create an attribute with type binaryData in your entity. And convert your array to data using

```
    NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(AnyObject)
```

And convert the array from data using

```
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSData)
```

By this way you can store any object in core data.

Comment: Been searching and searching for a clean way to save an array.  This works really well.  Thanks